# iOS extended (lot of search-parameters) fetch from Server and tableview design

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am building an app where I am fetching some data (e.g. persons, documents ...) from a server. I am building the app for iOS and Android. On Android i got it pretty decent looking ;), but on iOS I am not really sure how to properly design it(because I don't want to get it rejected by Apple). All of the apps, which I saw, that are fetching some data from a server just need one paameter and they are good to go. In my case I have a lot of parameters which can be used (for a person there is the name, email, postal address, phone, person type ...) and in the end you get a list (so I need a table view). Now I am not sure how to present that to the user. So far I have built a slide menu on the left (there is a navigation button which opens and closes it) and there I have placed  all of the additional search parameters.

The main search criteria would be by name and I thought to use it with the search bar and the search display controller(so you dont have to open the slider for a search over the names). The problem is that I am also using sliding cells (e.g. to call, send sms, send email to persons), and when searching with the search controller I always get a blank table (it seems that the search contoller can't handle custom cells). Then I switched to using the search bar (without the controller), but there is the problem that I am mssing the scope bar und the whole animation thing (I assume that I will have to create all of it manually)

Has anyone built some app like that ? What are the best practices for doing so (I am comming from the android world, so I am not sure what the average iOS user expects) ? For reloading the table I use just the pull-down mechanism ? Is that enough or do i need some additional bar buttons ?

It would be great if someone has a working example (in the appstore would also be fine), or a link to some explanation on this matter.

Kind regards

Comment: What you want to show on table, and based on which parameter you want to search. Mention your requirement.

For reloading table view, you can use the pull down mechanism, that is fine

Comment: As I said, on different objects i have different search parameters. For example on person i have the name, age, type, sex, phone number, email, postal address. I send this data to the server and get a list with person objects(that match my search) which I then represent in my tableview.The presentation of the data is not the problem, but the search parameters. I am struggling a little bit with this whole tableview data representation of the search parameters. It seems like i have to create all of it programatically (android seems here a lot better)

Comment: So what i get from your question, you are facing problem to show the search parameter, on the basis of which you want to search.

Then you keep all possible search parameter in the table view. on clicking on each table cell put a check mark. If user want to  search based on multiple criteria, then also you can show multiple check mark. And when user click search button, you request to the service with all the selected parameters. Am i right?

Comment: hmm, that with the check marks is actually not a bad idea ;), but not what I am looking for. I am looking for an "iOS-ish" way to represent the search criteria. Should i put them in a separate controller and navigate via navigation bar button ? Or is it fine to put them inside a slide menu ? The next thing is, should i use a tableview as the search criteria container or is a "normal" view enough ? Then there is the dropdown question (some of my search criteria are inside of dropdowns), since there is no dropdown in iOS what should be used (i saw few different approaches ...)...

Comment: In iOS, you can use tableView as drop down list. And you can navigate to separe controller as well as you can show them in custom popOver view.